# Python Depth First Search with Dict

Tags: python, algorithm, search, graph, depth-first-search

I keep seeing pseudocode for Depth First Search that is completely confusing to me in how it relates to my specific problem. I'm trying to determine whether or not a 'directed graph' is strongly connected.

If I have a dict with 2 strings (the first represents the source, the second represents the destination) and an optional number that represents edge weight:

```
{'Austin': {'Houston': 300}, 'SanFrancisco':  {'Albany': 1000}, 'NewYorkCity': { 'SanDiego': True }}
```

How can I implement some of the elements of the DFS? I know I can start at a vertex 'Austin' and that 'Houston' is another vertex. But I don't see how any of this works in Python code

Like I have this pseudocode:

```
function graph_DFS(start):
    # Input: start vertex
    S = new Stack()
    # Mark start as visited
    S.push(start)
    while S is not empty:
        node = S.pop()
        # Do something? (e.g. print)
        for neighbor in node’s adjacent nodes:
            if neighbor not visited:
                # Mark neighbor as visited
                S.push(neighbor)
```

I can see that I could pass 'Austin' as my start. But how in the world do I set 'Austin' to visited, and how do I see what nodes are adjacent to 'Austin'?

Plus how can I even use this algorithm to return true or false if the graph is strongly connected?

I am just having a really hard time seeing this transfer from pseudocode to code. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your data structure is unsuitable to implement a general graph because it does not allow to have more than one edge from a vertex. The dict values should be _lists_ of destinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see that I could pass 'Austin' as my start. But how in the world
>   do I set 'Austin' to visited, and how do I see what nodes are adjacent
>   to 'Austin'?

You can see in the code that you pop out 'Austin', so we will not be looking back at it. In your data structure, you allow only one edge from a vertex, so you will never have more than one neighbor.

> Plus how can I even use this algorithm to return true or false if the graph is strongly connected?

This is just a utility DFS function, the algorithm to find whether a graph is strongly connected or not, required running DFS twice. Basically, the hint is you want to know whether you get a tree or a forest on running DFS.

In my opinion, you should update your data structure such that the value of every key is a list (vertices to which it has an edge). You can store weights as well in the list in case you need them later.